# How To solve this type of inequation

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be  a regular $2\pi-$periodic function  .

How to find the functions that solve  this inequality $a \le f+f^{'}+f^{"} \le b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ .

Could you give me some books to deal with this type of problem?
Thanks

Comment: Since the function is periodic, can't you use a general fourier series and apply your condition to it?

Comment: thaanks ,yes but what type of information we can concloude about the fourier coefficients  from the inequality 
" fourier series is less than a constant" ?

Comment: What's the context, any special reason why you want to find such solutions? Classifying *all* such functions seems like a hard task. Finding some solutions is much easier. Take for example $f(x) = c + \sum c_n\sin(2\pi nx)$ with $c\in(a,b)$ and take $c_n$'s "small enough"

Comment: thank you , i would like to Classifying all such functions